# Share data between directive scope and controller $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here I created some sample for date picker, which is working fine but I need to set min and max date dynamically.. so i am passing the start and end date from 
Html like this my-datepicker  min="2013-07-23"   max="2015-07-23" in directive scope i get the value and I need to set this value in controller $scope.datepickerOptions = { startDate :min, endDate:max} some thing like this..

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ng-bootstrap-datepicker'])

app.directive('myDatepicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-datepicker ng-options="datepickerOptions"   ng-model="ngModel">',
    scope: {
      date: '=',
      ngModel: '=',
      min: '=',
      max: '=',
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.datepickerOptions = {
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
        weekStart: 0,
        startDate :'2013-07-23',
        endDate:'2015-07-23'
      };
    }
  };
})

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.date = '2013-08-12'
}]);

var appboot = angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/cletourneau/angular-bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/cletourneau/angular-bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<body>
<div>
     <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <my-datepicker ng-model ="date"  min="2013-07-23"   max="2015-07-23"></my-datepicker>
     <input id="datepickerMirror" type="text"  data-ng-model="date">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: ``$scope.min`` and ``$scope.max`` did not worked ??

Comment: I don't recommend `ng-bootstrap-datepicker`. It uses the bootstrap jQuery plugin and is not properly integrated with the `ng-model` controller. Use `uib-bootstrap-datepicker` instead. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker Further more, it implements attributes for `min-date` and `max-date`.

Comment: No, I need to use ng-bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope in the directive controller *IS* the isolated scope from the directive. You can just grab the values from $scope.min and $scope.max.

***Update*** The reason your code can't do this is because you're using the '=' binding which causes your directive to look for a variable named `2013-07-23` on your scope. You either need to put your value in a variable, or change the binding to '@' and use interpolation (the curly braces {{value}}), or surround your date value with single quotes inside the double quotes as in `min="'2013-07-23'" max="'2015-07-23'"`.

**https://plnkr.co/edit/Gp5SBtIAuLq5BzzIdKfp?p=preview**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ng-bootstrap-datepicker'])

app.directive('myDatepicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="text" ng-datepicker ng-options="datepickerOptions" ng-model="ngModel">',
    scope: {
      dateval: '=',
      ngModel: '=',
      min: '=',
      max: '=',
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.datepickerOptions = {
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
        weekStart: 0,
        startDate : $scope.min,
        endDate: $scope.max
      };
    }
  };
})

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dateval = '2013-08-12';
  $scope.min = '2013-07-23';
  $scope.max = '2015-07-23';
}]);

var appboot = angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
<link href="//rawgit.com/cletourneau/angular-bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/cletourneau/angular-bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/angular-bootstrap-datepicker.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>


<body>

<div>
     <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <my-datepicker ng-model="dateval"  min="min" max="max"></my-datepicker>
     <input id="datepickerMirror" type="text"  data-ng-model="dateval">
</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In single form I will put multiple date picker. so I will use same range for both.. this is not correct way...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, if you want multiple directives on the same page with different ranges, then you would just specify different min and max values on each directive. Whether those values come from the controller or whether you specify the values directly on the directive is up to you. However, if you do put it on the directive, you either need to change the binding to use '@' instead of '=', or you need to surround your date value with single quotes inside the double quotes as in `min="'2013-07-23'" max="'2015-07-23'"`

Comment: <my-datepicker ng-model="dateval"  min="'2013-07-23'" max="'2015-07-23'"></my-datepicker>               <my-datepicker ng-model="dateval1"  min="'2014-07-23'" max="'2016-07-23'"></my-datepicker>

Comment: ok, that should work now that you have the single quotes in there. Have you tried it?

Comment: If possible, can you modify the above ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99415/discussion-between-adam0101-and-suresh-b).

Comment: From our chat, here is an updated plunkr that has multiple date pickers with different min and max values. https://plnkr.co/edit/Gp5SBtIAuLq5BzzIdKfp?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer's Updated comments, the reason it's not working on UPDATE is that you're "binding" (scope params with "=") to a string literal. You're likely also getting a console error when you attempt to set that variable, something along the lines of object "non-assign".

That being said, is there a reason your directive NEEDS an isolated scope? If you just set the directive up using "scope: true", then your directive will prototypically inherit from the parent scope. This reduces portability, but it doesn't look like you're really shooting for that at this point.

To setup useful prototypical inheritance you'll need to also use the "as" syntax of ng-controller in your HTML view file. For the sake of example, let's say:

```
ng-controller="AppCtrl as appCtl"
```

Then move the initialization of datepickerOptions from your directive into your main AppCtrl controller. Personally I prefer the "dot" syntax as opposed to littering the scope with variables that are hard to track, so assign it to your controller instead of scope:

```
this.datepickerOptions = { /* min, max, etc */ }
```

Now in your directive (using scope:true), you can access that controller via the directive $scope. So in your directive's controller function:

```
$scope.datepickerOptions = $scope.appCtl.datepickerOptions
```

Note that I chose the "dot" syntax here because otherwise the prototypical inheritance would create a new scope element for datepickerOptions in your directive instead of traversing up and checking the scope chain. By using the dot syntax, the previous scope variable (appCtl) is accessed, and then the sub-object lookup (datepickerOptions) causes the app to traverse the scope chain up and get the object instead of shadowing it.

The last piece to address is ngModel. If you're following along up to now, all you have to do is set the ng-model (in your directive template) to read "appCtl.modelName" where modelName is the variable you want to use. Now your controller will have that variable assigned directly to it. If you want to do something when that value changes, add this to your AppCtrl controller:

```
// create a variable so that it can be used in callbacks where "this" changes
var _this = this;

// Create this by hand since its ng-model binding is added dynamically by the directive template
_this.modelName = null;

$scope.$watch(function() { return _this.modelName; }, function(val, oldVal)
{
   // do something here, remembering that _this contains a reference to the controller itself
});
```

Also note that in doing this you can get rid of that other input (datepickermirror) since all your data is already in your controller, and simply accessed by the directive.

Hope that helps!

Comment: In our chat the OP mentioned the need to have multiple date pickers on the same page with different min/max values. That's why an isolated scope is needed.

Comment: Ohh I totally missed that! Well in that case then he just needs to use variables for those values (if he wants to respond to changes) and get rid of the ngModel in the isolate scope. There's no need for that, since you'd be binding the ng-model of the template's Input element to a bi-directional scope variable. Then when the input changes, ng-model auto-triggers the update to the isolate scope var, and it can be watched for in the host controller. Alternatively there's also $rootScope.$on and $rootScope.$emit that could achieve similar results of responding to value changes. HTH!